# Display one of two bootstrap modals, depending on whether a javascript function returns true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap modals - one for successfully answering a quiz and the other for a failed answer.  I would like for when the check answer button is clicked, if the checked value returns true to display the modal-simple-success and if it is wrong to display modal-simple-failure.   I was struggling to figure out the javascript/jquery, and could use some help filling in the javascript function below.

Here is the button that initiates the function to see if it is the correct answer, and the modals being rendered below it:

```
<div class="checkAnswer" data-toggle="modal" href=""> //href should be #modal-simple-success or #modal-simple-failure
  <%= link_to_function "check answer", 'execute();', class: "btn btn-success"%>
</div>
<%= render 'shared/modal_simple_success' %>
<%= render 'shared/modal_simple_failure' %>
```

Here is the failure modal:

```
<div id="modal-simple-failure" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the success modal:

```
<div id="modal-simple-success" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-blue" id="successButton">Next step</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript, in which if the value is true, I would like to display model-simple-success using jquery or some alternative means

```
function checkValues(Result)
     checked = //working function to see true or false (don't need this)

    {
   if(checked)
            {

                //since true, display modal-simple-success
            }
            else
            {
                //since false, modal-simple-failure
            }
}
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: How do you check if an Answer is "right" (sucess) or "wrong" (failure)? Do you do an Ajax call? What about the js function `execute();`? How is it implemented? Does the function `checkValues(Result)` works but you just need the part to display the modal box? Or you need to implement the whole check answer part?

Comment: It actually drawn from the "gon" gem in rails, which passes backend data to javascript.  The "checked" function works fine - meaning I correctly receive a true or false value based on the input of the user.  So, I just need the part to display the relevant modal box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to invoke the bootstrap constructor with `show` option. ie.

```
function checkValues(Result){
   //your logic to see if it is checked
   if(checked)
     {
        $('#modal-simple-success').modal('show');
     }
     else
     {
        $('#modal-simple-failure').modal('show');
     }
  }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQdfY/)**

or just simplify it to :

```
function checkValues(Result){
       //your logic to see if it is checked
    var $modal = $('#modal-simple-failure');
    if(checked)
       $modal = $('#modal-simple-success');

    $modal.modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say use the following

```
if (checked) {
    body.appendChild("modal-simple-success")
}
else {
    body.appendChild("modal-simple-failure")
}
```

Should work to make those modals appear when you want them to.